# Cannot port forward with UFW on Ubuntu

Tags: lxc, ufw, port-forwarding

I am trying to get port fowarding to work to expose a LXC container, when using `ufw` on Ubuntu, but to no avail. I have constructed the following workflow from guides around the Internet ([1][2][3]); most notably the section about `/etc/ufw/before.rules` I see repeated all over the place but .... I cannot get it to work for me.

If anybody follows this guide and finds success.... do let me know (so I may first weep, and then fall back and write my own firewalling tool)

### Steps to reproduce/test

#### Setup

1. Test environment

   - New VM (I used virtualbox) "host1" with both a NAT and NAT Network interface

     - Install Ubuntu server 16.04 - just do a default installation
   - Second VM instance "host2", on same NAT Network
2. LXC installation on host1 - I am doing this with plain LXC, not introducing LXD setups yet

   - `sudo lxc-create -n web -t download -- -d centos -r 7 -a amd64`
   - `sudo lxc-start -n web`
   - `sudo lxc-attach -n web`

     - `yum install httpd ; yum enable httpd ; yum start httpd`
     - `exit`

We assume now that

- NAT Network interface on host1 is `enp0s8` and
- the container IP on host1 is `10.0.3.101`
- the IP of host1's enp0s8 is `10.0.2.6`
- See that with `sudo iptables -L -t nat` that the masquerading has already been configured by the LXC install

You may want to snapshot this base state.

At this point two routes: A-route with plain iptables, and B-route, the problematic one, with ufw

3. A - iptables

   - `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to "10.0.3.101:80"`
   - On the second host I can `wget http://10.0.2.6:8080` and this gives me the standard CentOS landing page. Success!

#### The problem

3. B - this can be done after a reboot of host1 or, if you snapshotted earlier, just revert. Either way, it behaves the same

   - Edit `/etc/default/ufw`

     - set `MANAGE_BUILTINS=yes`
     - set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`
   - Edit `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`

     - uncomment `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1`
   - Edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

     - Insert the nat lines (see below [4]) under the lead comments, but *above* the `*filter` line
     - Adjusting of course for the relevant configurations
   - `ufw allow 8080`
   - `ufw enable`
   - At this point, I cannot reach host1 from host2 with wget, firefox, etc - connection cannot be established
   - If I do `nc -l 8080` on host1 and try connecting again from host2, I get the HTTP header dump - indicating that no port forwarding is occurring. FAIL!

I've gone over my steps about short of 5 different times now with fresh VMs, digitalOcean droplets and AWS EC2 instances - no luck, always the same.

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong ...?

- [1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/370599/forward-port-to-lxc-guest-using-ufw#435286
- [2] https://gist.github.com/ShawnHuang/2726ef5e01a76e2eef55
- [3] https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#ip-masquerading
- [4] Nat lines:

  ```
  *nat
  :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
  -A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.101:80
  COMMIT

  # comments etc and the rest of the file, like,
  *filter
  ...
  ```

Comment: At this point I actually *have* written a firewalling script supporting profiles, raw entries and transferable configurations. I think I'll have to abandon using ufw for LXC machines... https://github.com/taikedz/vefirewall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there are a few more configuration steps that are needed to allow general traffic to flow:

At the top of `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, before the `*filter` section

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.101:80
COMMIT
```

And near the bottom, *before* the final `COMMIT`:

```
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 67 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 67 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

At the top of `/etc/ufw/after.rules`, before the filter section:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

That did it for my test environment, as outlined in the problem description.